# replace df index values with values from a list but ignore empty strings

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, replace, dataframe

I want to replace DF1.index.values with DF2[some_column].values HOWEVER i only want to replace if DF2[some_column].value is not null or empty string.

```
DF1.index.values

Index(['a','b','c','d']), dtype='object')

DF2[some_column].values

['base','','','net 1']
```

Expected output

```
Index(['base','b','c','net 1']), dtype='object')
```

My attempt:

```
DF1.index = DF2[some_column].values
```

It's incorrect because it replaces everything and thats not what I want, I'm only interested in not null or empty values.

Comment: does `DF2[some_column].replace('', DF1.index)` work?

Comment: Thanks EdChum but it wouldnt do fulfill what I plan to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where` to choose values by the condition from to sources:

```
DF1.index = DF2[some_column].where(DF2[some_column]!="", DF2.index)
```

So it will use `DF2[some_column]` values if `DF2[some_column]!=""` (in fact here we create a Series which is used as boolean index saying what data to choose for each raw), in the other case it will use `DF2.index` value.

As you don't want `nan` values also, you need `pd.notnull` functions. And to check both conditions use "logical and" function for pairs of values in two Series which is `&`.

So the final code is

```
DF1.index = DF2[some_column].where(
           (DF2[some_column]!="") & pd.notnull(DF2[some_column]), DF2.index)
```